# Find a constant such that....

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a $n$-dimensional space with basis {$e_1,\ldots,e_n$}. Show that there exists a constant $M\geq0$ such that $\vert c_k\vert\leq M\
\Vert x\Vert$ for every $x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n c_ke_k \in X$

I can't think of any. Maybe we will have to prove that  there is one without actually finding it. Or can we find a specific one?

Comment: Do you know that all norms on $\Bbb{R}^n$ are equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

First assume that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is an ONB (orthonormal basis), that is, $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=0$ whenever $i\neq j$, and $||e_i||^2=\langle e_i,e_i\rangle=1$. Then
$$
||x||^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\sum_{i,j}c_ic_j\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\sum_{i}c_i^2\langle e_i,e_i\rangle=\sum_{i}c_i^2\geq c_k^2
$$
and hence $|c_k|\leq||x||$ for each $k$.

Now assume that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is an arbitrary basis. Then we can transform this basis to an ONB $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ (i.e. by Gram-Schmidt), that is, there exists a transformation matrix $T$ such that $b_k=Te_k$. Then $Tx=\sum_{k}c_kb_k$. By what we have shown before, we have
$$
|c_k|\leq ||Tx||,
$$
and since $||Tx||\leq||T||\cdot||x||$, we obtain $|c_k|\leq||T||\cdot||x||$. That is, $M=||T||$.

ALTERNATIVE (as denoted in a comment): Define $||x||_c:=||(c_1,\ldots,c_n)||$. Then one can show that $||x||_c$ defines a norm in $\mathbb R^n$. Since all norms in $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, there exists a constant $M$ such that $||x||_c\leq M||x||$. Since $|c_k|\leq||x||_c$ for each $k$, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

The functions $p_i$ defined by
$$x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n c_ke_k \in X\longmapsto c_i,\qquad\qquad i=1,\cdots, n$$
are continuous (why?). Find a common bound $M$ for them on the unit ball (is a compact (why?)):
$$\forall x\in B(0,1): |c_i|=|p_i(x)|\le M.$$
Can you finish now?